# Displaying RGB values to the user

Tags: javascript

I'm building a random RGB value Generator and I want to display the values back to the User. I tried putting document.write(rgb) into the function newColor but when I press the button it gets rid of the HTML and only displays the javascript. How can I have the RGB values displayed on the fly? With the current set up it displays the first RGB value but when I press the button those values remain unchanged. Here's what I have so far.

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='jumbotron'>
<h1>Discover Color!</h1>
<button type='button' onclick="newColor()">New Color</button><br>
<script>
newColor();
function newColor() {
var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
window.rgb = "rgb(" + random1 + ", " + random2 + ", " + random3 +")"
document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb;
};

document.write('<p>Your random color is ' + rgb + '.</p>');
</script>
<p>
    Explore new colors with my random color generator! Hit refresh for a completely new background.
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases `document.write` is a terrible function to use. Instead, dynamically change the content of a element by selecting it with JavaScript, and setting new content.

In the following example, I added a `<code>` tag with an ID that gets selected via [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById), and update the text using the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) property.

### Example:

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='jumbotron'>
<h1>Discover Color!</h1>
<button type='button' onclick="newColor()">New Color</button><br>
<p>Your random color is <code id="rgbtext">rgb</code>.</p>
<p>
    Explore new colors with my random color generator! Hit refresh for a completely new background.
</p>
<script>
var rgbtextelement = document.getElementById('rgbtext');
newColor();
function newColor() {
  var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var rgb = "rgb(" + random1 + ", " + random2 + ", " + random3 +")";
  rgbtextelement.textContent = rgb;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb;
};
</script>
</div>
```